# How to vectorize a column into numerical value in Python

Tags: python

Lets say I have a column containing three values

```
a = ["Hello","Jello","Hello","Hello"]
```

I want to convert it into

```
a = [1,0,1,1]
```

What is the fastest way to do it Python.

Comment: Conversion based on what?

Comment: what if there would be another additional value like `["Hello","Jello","Hello","Hello", "Yellow"]` ? how should it be considered?

Comment: Why is "Hello" mapped to 1 and not 0?  It's seen first in the list (one possible criterion) and it sorts lower than "Jello" (another).  Is it just based on equality with "Hello"?  This question is very underspecified.

Comment: Are id's assigned according lexigoraphical order?

Comment: "Hello" can be mapped to 1 or 0 as long as it is different from "Jello"

Comment: *"Hello" can be mapped to 1 or 0* - OR `0` sounds conflicting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a list comprehension is the pythonic way to handle this.

```
a = [x == 'Hello' for x in a]
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, this will return a list of booleans, not integers. For integers, one has to modify the list comprehension:

```
a = [1 if x == 'Hello' else 0 for x in a]
```

or

```
a = [int(x == 'Hello') for x in a]
```

Props go to Maroun Maroun and Alberto Vassena for the two correct solutions.

**Edit2:** I timed both versions, here is the result:

First script:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

a = ['Hello', 'Jello', 'Hello', 'Hello']

start = timer()
b = [1 if x == 'Hello' else 0 for x in a]
end = timer()
print b
print('without cast: {}'.format(end - start))
```

Result:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
without cast: 2.86102294922e-06
```

Second script:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

a = ['Hello', 'Jello', 'Hello', 'Hello']

start = timer()
b = [int(x == 'Hello') for x in a]
end = timer()
print b
print('with cast: {}'.format(end - start))
```

Result:

```
[1, 0, 1, 1]
with cast: 5.96046447754e-06
```

So the test yields that using the `if else` construct is faster in this case.

Comment: This will return a list of `True` and `False` values, no? Also this assumes too much about OP's conversion algorithm.

Comment: You're right, this returns booleans. Apart from that, it does exactly what the OP specified.

Comment: `int(x == 'Hello')` fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used a list comprehension such as the following:

```
a = [(1 if 'Hello' == el else 0) for el in a]
```

But I think sobek's is definitely the best.
;)

Answer (score 1):

This is based on Sobek's answer as well - what if we do not know the elements present in the array, before hand. I guess this can be a solution:

```
a = ["Hello","Jello","Hello","Hello"]

b = [int(x == list(set(a))[0] ) for x in a ]

b = [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

This was the response I was looking for.

Comment: Note that casting is the slower implementation of the two.